# The number of product 3-cycles*2-cycles in the symmetric group $S_{5}$

Tags: symmetric-groups

Can anyone her tell me how to find the number of products 3-cycles*2-cycles

such that the 3-cycles and the 2-cycles are disjoints in the symmetric group $S_5$.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: there are $\frac{1}{m} \frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$ distinct $m$ cycles in $S_n$.

Comment: thank you sir for your answer, in fact i  know this fact but i could not reach the result of my question.